# DragDropEffect.Copy Resets itself to None

Tags: c#, wpf, scatterview

I have a `ScatterViewItem` in the `Scatterview`, whose manipulation is not handled by me. I also have a `RichTextBox` in the ScatterView, with property `AllowDrop = True`.

By default, the RichTextBox's `DragEnter` event fires whenever the ScatterViewItem is drag into it, which is correct. I checked DragDropEffect here, and it's `DragDropEffect.Move`. The `Drop` event fires appropriately after that.

I changed the DragDropEffect from `Move` to `Copy` in DragEnter, but the Drop event no longer fires. I checked the DragDropEffect again in `DragOver` and it somehow became `None`. I tried setting it in DragOver to `Copy` (again) but each time it will just become `None` by itself on the next trigger of DragOver.

The only time Drop event will fire is if DragDropEffect is set to `All` or `Move`. How do I change it to `DragDropEffect.Copy` and still fire the Drop event? I did set `e.Handled = true` after setting to DragDropEffect.Copy.

EDIT:
My apologises, I did manipulate the svi's drag and drop a little. In the ScatterView's `OnManipulationStarted`, I get the svi and called `svi.BeginDragDrop(svi.DataContext)`. That's all I did to the svi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `(DragEventArgs).AllowedEffects` property value? You can only set the `(DragEventArgs).Effects` property to one of the values specified by the `(DragEventArgs).AllowedEffects` property. If `DragDropEffects.Copy` is not an option found in the `(DragEventArgs).AllowedEffects` property enumeration, then you will *not* be able to use that function.

You can set that option when you create your data object and call `DoDragDrop`:

```
DragDrop.DoDragDrop(item, dragData, DragDropEffects.All);
```

UPDATE >>>

As I said, normally, you set the allowable `DragDropEffects` enumeration when you call `DoDragDrop`... after seeing that you have called the `SurfaceDragCursor.BeginDragDrop` method, I looked online at the [SurfaceDragDrop.BeginDragDrop Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.surfacedragdrop.begindragdrop.aspx) page at MSDN and found this:

```
public static SurfaceDragCursor BeginDragDrop (
    FrameworkElement dragSource,
    FrameworkElement draggedElement,
    FrameworkElement cursorVisual,
    Object data,
    IEnumerable<InputDevice> inputDevices,
    DragDropEffects allowedEffects
)
```

I'm guessing that the last parameter here is where you set the `DragDropEffects` allowable effect enumeration.

Comment: Hmmm did you mix up `Effects` and `AllowedEffects`? I can't find out what's the AllowedEffects, there's no such property in `DragEventArgs` in `DragEnter`. I didn't call `DragDrop.DoDragDrop`, I called `svi.BeginDragDrop` instead which creates a `SurfaceDragCursor`. I changed to `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` and `DragEnter` doesn't even fire now. Pardon me but my knowledge of Drag and Dropping surface items is still very weak...

Comment: in `DragEnter`, I checked the `(SurfaceDragDropEventArgs).Cursor.AllowedEffects` and it's `Move`.

Comment: Yes, I *did* get them mixed up... thanks for pointing that out... I've updated my answer now. Also, if your `AllowedEffects` only says `Move`, then you can only move and not copy.